# Efficiently check element exists in map c++

Tags: c++, performance, dictionary

I am aware of the .find() method to check whether or not an element exists in a map. But suppose i have a map -- map -- with about 2000 elements and I want to add an element to the list. I first have to check if the element exists. Isn't it a bit inefficient to use .find() because the iterator has to 'iterate' over element in the map? Is there a more efficient and less time consuming way to check whether or not an element exists in a map?

Comment: If you need ultra efficiency, you might want to use a sorted container that allows binary search.

Comment: Why not just [`insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) it? It'll let you know if it was already there.

Comment: @Michael: I believe this is referring to a `std::map`, which is already a tree.

Comment: "I first have to check if the element exists." no you do not

Comment: You want to check that the key isn't there, not the value, right?

Comment: @Slava That is unclear from the question. It could be that OP doesn't want to add a new element if one with the same key is already in the map.

Comment: @Slava and you just said in the other question that your telepathy machine is not working - yet you clearly demonstrate that you use it (because there is no other way you could reach that conclusion without looking at OP's case)

Comment: @juanchopanza: Yes I want to check if the key already exists. Not the value

Comment: @SergeyA no I do not use it, I am just saying "for `std::map` one does not have to check if value exists before inserting". If for OP it is not fine by logic of his program it is OP's burden to express that clearly.

Comment: @DuckDodgers your question is not clear and missing much important information, if you want a good answer make a good question.

Comment: `find` is a misleading name. It is not a linear search, it is a fast lookup. Its the same algorithm as `[key]` lookup , it just has different behavior when the item is not in the map

Answer (score 3):

`std::map` has logarithmic look-up complexity, so you won't have to visit all the elements to determine whether an element is in the map.

On the other hand, you can make the look-up and insert operation more concise by using `std::map::emplace` or `std::map::insert`:

```
auto [iter, ok] = the_map.emplace(the_key, a_value);
if (ok) {
  // element was not in map so got inserted
}
```

This assumes that `a_value` either already exists, or that it is not an issue to construct it even if it does not end up being inserted into the map.

Comment: There could be cases when this doesn't actually work. This would require constructing (and than discarding in case of failure) an `a_value`, but it might not be desired.

Comment: @SergeyA Yes, indeed. I added a note about that.

Comment: I'll just mention that this nifty `auto[]` syntax requires C++17.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use 'find and insert' idiom (and that could be because you can't construct a value object for the same key twice under any circumstances) and you are concerned about twice logarithmic complexity, you'd have to use `std::map::equal_range`.

The way to do this would be first use `equal_range` with your key, and than use one of returned iterators as a hint to insert.